# Where does the C++ standard allow pointers to undefined types?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration, language-lawyer

Where in the C++ spec is this allowed?  It's cool.  I want to know how this is spec'd.  I didn't realize the spec allowed having a pointer to a undefined type.

```
class T;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   int x;
   T* p = reinterpret_cast<T*>(&x);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Um, how is that allowed? Because I'm pretty sure that `reinterpret_cast` is either implementation defined behavior or *undefined behavior*. Either way, it's not defined by the spec, so I'm not sure if it could be considered "allowed". Or are you talking about just the forward declaration?

Comment: And why would this be cool?

Comment: @Bart Because you can do nasty things, maybe?

Comment: Here's an example of why I think it is cool. http://arduino.cc/forum/index.php/topic,91314.msg685761.html#msg685761

Comment: @Rob, I didn't realize the spec allowed having a pointer to a undefined type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you're doing *may* be legal, but that depends on the real definition of `class T`, so we can't know for sure based on the code you've shown.

Starting with C++11 §3.9.2/3:

> Pointers to incomplete types are allowed although there are restrictions on what can be done with them.

Those restrictions are listed in §3.2/4:

> A class type `T` must be complete if:
>
> - an object of type `T` is defined, or
> - a non-static class data member of type `T` is declared, or
> - `T` is used as the object type or array element type in a *new-expression*, or
> - an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is applied to a glvalue referring to an object of type `T`, or
> - an expression is converted (either implicitly or explicitly) to type `T`, or
> - an expression that is not a null pointer constant, and has type other than `void*`, is converted to the type pointer to `T` or reference to `T` using an implicit conversion, a `dynamic_cast` or a `static_cast`, or
> - a class member access operator is applied to an expression of type `T`, or
> - the `typeid` operator or the `sizeof` operator is applied to an operand of type `T`, or
> - a function with a return type or argument type of type `T` is defined or called, or
> - a class with a base class of type `T` is defined, or
> - an lvalue of type `T` is assigned to, or
> - the type `T` is the subject of an `alignof` expression, or
> - an *exception-declaration* has type `T`, reference to `T`, or pointer to `T`.

The 6th bullet *appears* pertinent here, as we can see in §5.2.10/7 that a `reinterpret_cast` between pointer types is defined in terms of `static_cast`:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type. When a prvalue `v` of type “pointer to `T1`” is converted to the type “pointer to cv `T2`”, the result is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`. Converting a prvalue of type “pointer to `T1`” to the type “pointer to `T2`” (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

But because `reinterpret_cast` `static_cast`s to `void*` first, *then* to the real resulting pointer type, that 6th bullet doesn't apply.

So, so far you're still in legal territory, despite `T` being an incomplete type. However, if it turns out that `T` is not a standard-layout type or has stricter alignment requirements than `int`, then the last sentence in §5.2.10/7 holds true and you're invoking UB.

Answer (score 4):

The only thing you're allowed to do after casting a pointer to an unrelated type (other than `char*`), is cast back to the original pointer type.

@cli_hlt beat me to providing the section.

Here's the rule itself:

> An object pointer can be explicitly converted to an object pointer of a different type.
>   When a prvalue `v` of  type "pointer to `T1`"  is  converted  to  the  type  "pointer  to  *`cv`* `T2`",  the  result  is `static_cast<cv T2*>(static_cast<cv  void*>(v))` if both `T1` and `T2` are standard-layout types (3.9) and the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`, or if either type is `void`.  Converting a prvalue of type
>   "pointer to `T1`" to the type "pointer to `T2`" (where `T1` and `T2` are object types and where the alignment requirements of `T2` are no stricter than those of `T1`) and back to its original type yields the original pointer value. The result of any other such pointer conversion is unspecified.

The *strict aliasing rule* prohibits access to an object through an unrelated type.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/7005988/103167

Another rule somewhat related to your question is found in section 5.4:

> The operand of a cast using the cast notation can be a prvalue of type "pointer to incomplete class type".  **The destination type of a cast using the cast notation can be "pointer to incomplete class type"**  If both the operand and destination types are class types and one or both are incomplete, it is unspecified whether the `static_cast` or the `reinterpret_cast` interpretation is used, even if there is an inheritance relationship
>   between the two classes.

Answer (score 2):

Section 5.2.10 (7) for your case (as of ISO/IEC14882:1998(E), as well as in the 2011 FDIS).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you perceive as being allowed. There is a guarantee that you can `reinterpret_cast` from one pointer type to a sufficiently big other pointer type and back to the original type again and will be the original pointer. The specification for this is in 5.2.10 [expr.reinterpret.cast]. That is, the following is guaranteed to work:

```
T* ptr = ...;
S* sptr = reinterpret_cast<S*>(ptr);
T* tptr = reinterpret_cast<T*>(sptr);
assert(ptr == tptr);
```

We had an out of session discussion earlier this week on this topic: if the Death Station 9000 implementation (which would be a conforming implementation of C++ but also tries to break user code wherever it is allowed to do so) XORs the bit pattern of the pointer with a bit pattern randomly chosen at the beginning of the program execution, would this be a permissible implementation if the types involved in the `reinterpret_cast<T>(x)` are not involving `char`. The consensus was that this would be OK.

Comment: I now realize my question is not that clear.  I didn't realize the spec allowed having a pointer to a undefined type.

Comment: I also just realized that my `reinterpret_cast<>()`s used the wrong type! I'll fix this in a second (sorry for any confusion I might have caused): `S` and `T` are meant to be two layout compatibly types and they were meant to be used in the casts.